# How to overwrite and perform actions on webpage with AbotX Javascriptrendering

Tags: c#, web-crawler, abot

I am trying to use the [AbotX crawler](https://abotx.org/) to crawl a site where I need to render the javascript and the press a span tag on it.

I've used the Abot crawler a lot and expected to having to overwrite some of the classes just as I have on previous occasions had to expand on for instance, the CrawlDecisionMaker.

But I can't seem to find out where to start, I expect I have to writing something like:

```
var implemnts = new ImplementationOverride(config);
implemnts.JavascriptRenderer = new PhantomJsRendererTest(config);
```

and extend the PhantomJsRenderer to be able to get it to click a button on the rendered page.

But since I can not see what the existing class does or find any information about where to start, I am completely lost.

I wanted to tag the post Abot and AbotX, but I do not have the required reputation for that.

Comment: If my answer is sufficient can you please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AbotX](https://abotx.org) (with IsJavascriptRenderingEnabled = true) will retrieve the page source and execute all javascript to get a final page rendering. This final rendering includes all content (html/css) even content that was added/modified using javascript. It does not allow you to execute javascript any further.

If you need to interact with the page further then a web crawler is not likely what you need. You would need to use a browser automation framework like [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/) or [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). Those are headless browsers that will allow you to interact with the page just like you can in a browser.