# C# Crawler can't load dynamic content

Tags: c#, request, web-crawler, abot

I am using the Abot library to crawl a web page. The crawler can request the pages correctly but the problem is that almost all of the content is loaded dynamically through knockout.js. The crawler currently has no way of requesting this content which results in only a small part of the page being loaded.

I've tried making the program wait in hopes of the requests for the dynamic being sent anyways but that doesn't seem to work.

I want the entire page to be loaded but instead, only the base of the page is loaded.

What can I do to make the crawler request all data?

Thanks!

Comment: Does "abot" execute JavaScript it encounters? - that's what it will need to do, if it does not you will need to use something else.

Comment: Maybe [How to overwrite and perform actions on webpage with AbotX Javascriptrendering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35484689/205233) holds a clue. Sounds like `IsJavascriptRenderingEnabled` could be what you're looking for.

Comment: It cant, you need an automation framework.

Comment: @AlexK.it doesn't unfortunately.

Comment: @Filburt I don't think Abot has that option. Just AbotX. And sadly that's only the paid version for $299

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ do you have any suggestions? I could do selenium if you know of a crawler compatible with it.

Comment: Selenium would suffice just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

Not possible this way, you need something that can handle the JS for you like browsers do.
I would recommend Splash from Scrapy (It can be integrated with any language through it's REST API).

But in my humble opinion, if you don't need an enterprise solution don't use C# for web crawling, there are easiest solutions and more complete libraries in python for example.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into using python and Scrapy.